# Is there a cc equivalent to the -Wformat gcc flag?

Tags: gcc, cc

My company uses a massive makefile which uses CC to compile, not gcc.  I would like to use the `-Wformat` flag to show errors where types in `printf` and `sprintf` don't match with the provided arguments.

Does anyone know a similar flag in CC which will provide this functionality?  The task currently compiles fine, yet I know for a fact there are mismatched types in 100's of places, I need to find them.

I am compiling on Sun architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: `cc` is a platform dependent compiler. Please specify your platform.

Comment: I am compiling on sun machines.  Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Complete Solaris Studio cc and CC documentation is available at
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solarisstudio/documentation/index.html

There are also man pages cc(1) and CC(1) installed on your system.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18659_01/html/821-2676/cc.1.html

You might also run the source code thru lint(1)
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18659_01/html/821-2676/lint.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Sun's cc, but if you're talking about 100 places, maybe it worth the effort to compile ith gcc